# PWM Driver for PIC12F1572

Tags: led, pic, pwm, automotive, learning

I have rear lights for car (VW Passat) controlled by default with PWM. I want to create another circuit who do like follow:
When I press brake, car send PWM into LEDs and turn it ON. I want to use this signal to turn ON my circuit. I used a "basic driver" with diode and transistor, but doesn't work (with PWM I can't open the transistor to set R1 to 0) if I use the same circuit with DC voltage is working as I expected.

Could you please help me with ideas how to create this circuit?
The main idea is: when I have PWM (12V 200Hz) on input pin (but I can't connect directly 12V into uc), turn on the output pin of uc.

Sorry if I'm not very specific, but I can explain more if is needed, I'm new in electronics and want to learn more.
Thank you in advance.
[image: Used Circuit]

Comment: _"12 V Battery" is 5V regulated voltage_ - so... fix it?

Comment: What is the duty cycle of the PWM signal? Does it vary? What is the minimum duty necessary for the PIC to be notified?

Comment: What is RA4 supposed to send when the PWM is active? Just a constant logic high? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

RA2 should be configured for

- `TRISA5 = 1` (input);
- `ANSA5` is not implemented so the pin will naturally be in digital mode;
- `WPUA5 = 0` to disable weak pullup; and
- `INLVLA2 = 1` (Schmitt trigger mode).

In this mode,

- Vil <= 0.2 Vdd (by parameter D031),
- Vih >= 0.8 Vdd (by D041),
- Leakage |IIL| ~ 5 nA <= 125 nA,
- CIO <= 50 pF (D101A).

Assume Vdd = 5.0.

The 1N4148 forward drop increases by about 100 mV on every current decade at 25C, below 600 mV at 1 mA. This implies a drop of ~200mV at 100 nA, though this is a pretty vague ballpark because most specsheets do not specify drops at this low current, and there is inter-device variation.

For this application, use a Schottky instead. The 1N5817 is a common part that, for every 100 mV, increases in forward current by a factor of about 40, below 300 mV at 50 mA (with the same specification caveats).

$$0.3 - 0.1 \log _{40} \left( \frac {50 \text{mA}} {125 \text{nA}} \right) < 0$$

so assume the forward drop to be negligible. That means we assume that in the forward-biased case, input voltage is equal to Vdd. In the reverse-biased case, leakage at 25C is specified against percentage of rated peak reverse voltage. For a typical 1N5817, Vr < 20V. These percentages range from the input-low case of 5/20 = 25% to the input-high case of (5 - 4)/20 = 5%. At 25% (input-low), Ileak ~ 1.5 uA. Every 20% the leakage reduces by a factor of about 1.5 below 2.5 uA at 50%, so for another log estimate, input-high leakage can be estimated at:

$$ 2.5 \text{uA} / 1.5^ { \frac {0.5 - 0.05} {0.2} } \approx 1 \text{uA} $$

Since 1 uA of diode leakage is greater than even the worst-case port leakage of 125 nA, we can assume that in the input-high case the port voltage will always equal Vdd, and don't need to worry about 4V minimum input voltage.

A model for input-low can be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAG17Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In other words, assuming the diode leakage estimate is roughly true, to be able to pull the input port down to 1V, the resistor must be at most

$$R_1 \le \frac 1 {1.625 \text{uA}} \approx 615 \text{k} \Omega$$

Any higher, and voltage low may become too great to switch the Schmitt; but also you don't want the resistance to be too low, because you need to protect the PIC against automotive voltages. Something conservative like 100k should be safe. At this resistance, voltage low will be between:

$$V_{il} \ge \left( 100 \text{k}\Omega \right) \left( 5 \text{nA} + 1.5 \mu\text{A} \right) $$
$$V_{il} \le \left( 100 \text{k}\Omega \right) \left( 125 \text{nA} + 1.5 \mu\text{A} \right) $$
$$ 150.5 \text{mV} \le V_{il} \le 162.5 \text{mV} \ll 1 \text{V} $$

The AC model of the port adds

- up to 50 pF from CIO;
- a dynamic reverse junction capacitance of anywhere from 300 pF (input high) to ~65 pF (input low);
- port leakage as anywhere from 5V/(5 nA through 125 nA) -> 1 Gohm through 40 Mohm; and
- reverse diode leakage of 0 (input high) to 1.5 uA (input low)

Let's assume that you want to turn on the input for a 200 Hz duty cycle of at least 10%. That means a minimum on-time of 1/200 * 0.1 = 500 us.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIsVmB.png)</sup>

At that scale, the parasitics are negligible, and you can base your time constant on the 100k resistor and a 10 nF capacitor. This will filter out noise.

[image: transients]

Without knowing anything else about the application, those three passives (D1, R1, C1) will offer some filtration and protection.

Answer (score 0):

When Q1 is not conducting, there will be no current through R1, so the transistor's collector voltage will be the same as that of the supply, 12 V.  Is that more than the microcontroller can tolerate?

It appears that when the PWM signal is high, you'll get around 113 uA base current.  If we assume the current amplification is 100 to 400, then the collector current will be between 11 mA and 45 mA.  But it isn't clear what you're doing with that current.  It seems to me that the sensed voltage (the collector's voltage) will be either roughly 0 V or 12 V, depending on whether or not the transistor conducts.  I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is a mistake in circuit "12 V Battery" is 5V regulated voltage. Current is used just to turn on or off the uc input. I want something like that: when PWM is present, input pin is high and will be kept high as long PWM is present. When PWM is stopped input pin will be low. What I want to mention is I think should be a "buffer": now, input is toggled on / off fast and also toggle my output. I want to somehow transform PWM into digital signal -> PWM ON = keep input high (not on-off-on-ff...) & PWM OFF= keep input low.